# Is there something similar to 'zoomToRegion' in Android?

Tags: android, zooming, region, pan

I want to zoom in or out of the map depending on where markers on my map are placed. The markers are dynamic so I can not chose a static zoom level. I understand that there is 'zoomToRegion' method in iOS to acheive this. Is there something similar in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
You have to use the method `zoomToSpan` of [MapController](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html).

```
// zoom into map to box of results
int centerLat = (int)(((maxLat-minLat)/2+ minLat)*1E6);
int centerLon = (int)(((maxLon-minLon)/2 + minLon)*1E6);
mapView.getController().animateTo(new GeoPoint( centerLat, centerLon));
mapView.getController().zoomToSpan((int)((maxLat-minLat)*1E6), (int)((maxLon-minLon)*1E6));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in zoomToSpan I can give only one co-ordinate. I want to display a region i.e rectangle (4 co-ordinates).Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It does point me in the right directions. Thanks a million :)